# python | как изменить ширину консоли в linux?

Tags: python, linux, manjaro

портирую свой скрипт на линукс и там есть такой момент:

```
windowLen = 121 #длина окна скрипта
if sys.platform == "win32":
    os.system(f"mode con:cols={windowLen} lines=29") # устанавливаем длину окна скрипта
```

как сделать такую же штуку только для линукса дефолтным функционалом питона

P.S. в нете натыкался на такое решение `os.terminal_size(columns=87, lines=23)`, но по каким то причинам, у меня оно вызывает вот такую ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: structseq() missing required argument 'sequence' (pos 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.terminal_size` это не функция, а ответ на `os.get_terminal_size`.

Аналог команды `mode con` в Linux это stty

```
os.system(f"stty cols {windowLen} rows 23")
```

но это не меняет размер окна, только содержимого.

Есть ещё команда resize - меняет и размер окна и размер x-консоли:

```
os.system(f"resize -s 23 {windowLen}")
```

Но она не сработает в текстовой консоле не в иксах.

В общем виде:

```
if sys.platform == 'linux':
    if 'xterm' in os.environ.get('TERM'):
        os.system(f"resize -s 23 {windowLen}")
    else:
        os.system(f"stty cols {windowLen} rows 23")
```